# 405 method not allowed for my flask application with socket io

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

This is the session.html where the jquery is. I have worked out there is nothing wrong with the jquery but cannot see why i am getting 405 method not allowed. This app uses flask and jquery and python.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
<input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Messages"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on( 'connect', function() {
      socket.emit( 'my event', {
        data: 'User Connected'
      } )
      var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
        let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
          user_name : user_name,
          message : user_input
        } )
        $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
      } )
    } )
    socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
      console.log( msg )
      if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
        $( 'h3' ).remove()
        $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
      }
    })
</script>
```

This is the main.py where i run the server using flask.

```js
@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET','POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message + stack trace (if it exists)?

Comment: There was no error message. Whenever i pressed send the page would just go on 405 method no allowed. Thanks in advance. However, in the console it also said bad request. Thanks for replying.

Comment: What is the **target** of your form ? I would guess you are making a POST request to an endpoint that only accepts GET, like for example '/'.

Comment: I dont have a target for the form. The jquery in the script handles the form.

Comment: A form always has an implicit target even if it's set in Javascript. Are you sure the request is not being sent to / (route sessions) ? Add a print just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing the following message in your server logs.

> The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)

This issue is related to an outdated version of Socket.IO in the client web browser. In other words, your JavaScript is outdated in the session.

Update the Socket.IO script to the following (or obtain the most recent from https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/):

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"
  integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```